# The rules of Conway's Game of Life aren't working in my Javascript version. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cellular-automata

I'm working on some code for a javascript implemenation of Conway's Game of Life Cellular Automata for a personal project, and I've reached the point of encoding the rules. I am applying the rules to each cell, then storing the new version in a copy of the grid. Then, when I'm finished calculating each cell's next state, I set the first grid's state to the second's one, empty the second grid, and start over. Here's the code I used for the rules:

```js
//10x10 grid
let ecells = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

let cells = empty_cells;

let new_cells = cells;

let paused = true;

function Cell(x, y) {
    return cells[y][x];
}

function Nsum(i, j) {
    if (i >= 1 && j >= 1) {
        return Cell(i - 1, j) + Cell(i + 1, j) + Cell(i, j - 1) + Cell(i - 1, j - 1) + Cell(i + 1, j - 1) + Cell(i, j + 1) + Cell(i - 1, j + 1) + Cell(i + 1, j + 1);
    }
}

//One can manually change the state of the cells in the "cells" grid, 
//which works correctly. Then, one can run the CA by changing the "paused"
//value to false.

function simulation() {
    for (i = 0; i < cells[0].length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            if (Cell(i, j)) {
                ctx.fillRect(20*i - 0.5, 20*j, 20, 20);
                if (!paused) {
                    if (Nsum(i, j) == 2 || Nsum(i, j) == 3) new_cells[j][i] = 1;
                    else new_cells[j][i] = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                ctx.clearRect(20*i - 0.5, 20*j, 20, 20);
                if (!paused) {
                    if (Nsum(i, j) == 3) new_cells[j][i] = 1;
                    else new_cells[j][i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!paused) cells = new_cells;
    new_cells = empty_cells;
    requestAnimationFrame(simulation);
}

simulation();
```

The rule logic is inside the nested for loop, Nsum is the function that calculates the neighborhood sum of the current cell. I say ncells[j][i] instead of ncells[i][j] because in a 2d array you address the row first.

I didn't try much, but I can't imagine a solution. Help!

Comment: Usually you compute the *next* value of the cells first, then you update all the cells with the new value. If you count the neighbors while updating, you get the wrong results.

Comment: That's what I'm doing :D probably it is unclear from my post, but the grid ncells, is a copy of the existing grid, not the grid itself. When ncells is calculated, it is pasted onto the normal grid, and it is then cleared in order to be calculated again.

Comment: Well you'll have to debug it systematically. And the order of addressing the cells, well, it doesn't really matter as long as you're consistent. It mattered a long time ago in FORTRAN kind-of but in a modern language the array layout is conceptual more than physical.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)! I will try to debug it, but, I would like to ask you, are there any problems with the code that I am missing? Thank you :D

Comment: Please show the [mcve] (the game of life is generally pretty small) because right now there's no proof that the code you're showing is where things go wrong (if it was, given how few lines you're showing, you'd probably have already figured out the problem on your own =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your comment! I edited my post to include a minimum reproducible example!

Comment: Please remember to _verify_ that the code you're showing runs. If you try to turn your code into a runnable snippet, and instead of drawing to the canvas, you just update the textContent of a `<pre>` with the content of ncells, you'll get _loads_ of errors about variables that don't exist =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh I am very truly sorry! I forgot to change the names of some variables I copy-pasted from the editor. Now it must not have such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by not bothering with rows vs. columns, because (and this is the nice thing about the game of life), it doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is what the eight values *around* a cell are doing, so as long as we stick to one ordering, the code will simply do the right thing.

Which means we can get rid of that `Cell` function (on that note, that's not how you name things in JS. Variables and functions use lowerCamelCase, classes/constructor functions use UpperCamelCase and constant values use UPPER_SNAKE_CASE).

Then, let's fix `Nsum` because it's ignoring the edges right now, which is not how the game of life works: in order to count how many neighbours a cell has, we need to sum *up to* eight values, but not every cell has eight neighbours. For instance, (0,0) has nothing to the left/above it. So let's rewrite that to a loop:

```js
function getNeighbourCount(i, j) {
  const cells = currentCells;
  let sum = 0;
  // run over a 3x3 block, centered on i,j:
  for (let u = -1; u <= 1; u++) {
    // ignore any illegal values, thanks to "continue";
    if (i + u < 0 || i + u >= cellCount) continue;
    for (let v = -1; v <= 1; v++) {
      // again, ignore any illegal values:
      if (j + v < 0 || j + v >= cellCount) continue;
      // and skip over [i][j] itself:
      if (u === 0 && v === 0) continue;
      sum += cells[i + u][j + v];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

We can also take advantage of the fact that we *know* that we're setting our update board to zeroes before we start calculating updates, so we don't need to set any cells to 0: they already are.

```js
...
  // by copying the empty cells array, we start with
  // all-zeroes, so we don't need to set anything to 0.
  const next = structuredClone(emptyCells);

  for (let i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
      // is this cell alive?
      const alive = currentCells[i][j] === 1;

      // we only need to calculate this once, not three times =)
      const neighbourCount = getNeighbourCount(i, j);

      if (alive && (neighbourCount === 2 || neighbourCount === 3)) {
        next[i][j] = 1;
      } else if (neighbourCount === 3) {
        next[i][j] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
...
```

So if we put all that together, and instead of using a canvas we just use a preformatted HTML element that we print our grid into, we get:

```js
const cellCount = 10;

// Let's define the same grid, but rather than harcoding it,
// let's just generate it off of a single number:
const emptyCells = [...new Array(cellCount)].map((_) => [...new Array(cellCount)].fill(0));

// Then, initialize the current cells from that empty grid.
let currentCells = structuredClone(emptyCells);

// To see things work, let's add a "glider"
[[0, 1],[1, 2],[2, 0],[2, 1],[2, 2]].forEach(([i, j]) => (currentCells[i][j] = 1));

// Then, our control logic: we'll have the sim run
// with a button to pause-resume the simulation.
let nextRun;
let paused = false;
toggle.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  paused = !paused;
  if (paused) clearTimeout(nextRun);
  else runSimulation();
});

// And then: run the program!
showBoard();
runSimulation();

// It doesn't matter where we put functions in JS: the parser first
// reads in every function, and only *then* starts running, letting
// us organize things in terms of "the overall program" first, and
// then "the functions that our program relies on" after.

// draw our board with □ and ■ for dead and live cells, respectively.
function showBoard() {
  board.textContent = currentCells
    .map((row) => row.join(` `).replaceAll(`0`, `□`).replaceAll(`1`, `■`))
    .join(`\n`);
}

// our simulation just runs through the grid, updating
// an initially empty "next" grid based on the four
// Game of Life rules.
function runSimulation() {
  const next = structuredClone(emptyCells);
  for (let i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
      const alive = currentCells[i][j] === 1;
      const neighbourCount = getNeighbourCount(i, j);
      if (alive && (neighbourCount === 2 || neighbourCount === 3)) {
        next[i][j] = 1;
      } else if (neighbourCount === 3) {
        next[i][j] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // update our grid, draw it, and then if we're not paused,
  // schedule the next call half a second into the future.
  currentCells = next;
  showBoard();
  if (!paused) {
    nextRun = setTimeout(runSimulation, 500);
  }
}

// In order to count how many neighbours we have, we need to
// sum *up to* eight values. This requires making sure that
// we check that a neighbour even exists, of course, because
// (0,0), for instance, has nothing to the left/above it.
function getNeighbourCount(i, j, cells = currentCells) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let u = -1; u <= 1; u++) {
    if (i + u < 0 || i + u >= cellCount) continue;
    for (let v = -1; v <= 1; v++) {
      if (j + v < 0 || j + v >= cellCount) continue;
      if (u === 0 && v === 0) continue;
      sum += cells[i + u][j + v];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<pre id="board"></pre>
<button id="toggle">play/pause</button>
```